# How do I use @font-face with the Noto Emoji font by character references?

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have two local files

```
index.html
NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf
```

I have downloaded `NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf` from [google.com/get/noto/](https://www.google.com/get/noto/).

The `index.html` contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Emoji</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Noto Emoji Regular";
            src: url("NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf");
        }
        span {
            font-family: "Noto Emoji Regular";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Emoji: <span>&#x1F595;</span>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the `index.html` in my browser, it does not display the text in the `span` in Emoji. Using Chrome DevTools (F12 in Chrome) it says the `span` *does* have the correct `Noto Emoji Regular` font.

How do I display an Emoji icon from this font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- Make sure your directory is correct.

2- You should add format of font src:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "Noto Emoji Regular";
 src: url('NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

3- `&#x1F595`; is not correct with Noto Emoji font. Try with: `&#x2139;` (ℹ)

For cross browsers, you have to [convert](http://www.font2web.com/) to web fonts, example:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Noto Emoji Regular';
 src: url('NotoEmoji-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
 src: url('NotoEmoji-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
   url('NotoEmoji-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
   url('NotoEmoji-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
   url('NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Chrome, Safari, Android, iOS */
   url('NotoEmoji-Regular.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: The directory is correct, as stated they are in the same folder. DevTools does not show any error. The format is not necessary. I am not looking for cross browser solutions.

Comment: Your font-face is correct. I think character in span tag is wrong. I tried with &#x2139, it work fine. Tell me about your result :)

Comment: It worked! But your answer contains too much diversion in my opinion. I'd accept it as an answer if it's more correct. The only correct answer is that that specific character is not supported by the font.

Comment: My option 1 and 2 are remind you. For cross browsers just is suggestion :)

Comment: Because I can't comment to your post, I have to show some options for you. You can  up/down vote my answer. :)